# fcm-django add badge to Aps for ios platform

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use fcm-django library

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        devices = FCMDevice.objects.filter(user=user)

        body_data = {
            "title": "Title text",
            "body": "Click to explore more",
        }
        extra_data = {"type": "some information", "link": "https://google.com", "badge": str(10)}

        for device in devices:
            try:
                if device.type == "ios":
                    device.send_message(Message(notification=FCMNotification(**body_data), data=extra_data))
                else:
                    device.send_message(Message(data={**body_data, **extra_data}))
            except Exception as e:
                return Response({'error_message': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I need add badge value to Aps for ios. I've tried

```
apns = {
            "badge": 10,
        }
device.send_message(Message(notification=FCMNotification(**body_data), data=extra_data, apns=Aps(apns)))
```

But got error and no PN. How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
device.send_message(Message(
                        notification=FCMNotification(**body_data),
                        data=extra_data,
                        apns=APNSConfig(
                            payload=APNSPayload(
                                aps=Aps(badge=10),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ))
```